# How do you count the amout of duplicate characters in a string ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a string

```
s = "chineedne"
```

I am trying create a function that can count the amount of duplicate characters in my string or any string

tried

```
s.each_char.map { |c| c.find.count { |c| s.count(c) > 1 }}
#=> NoMethodError: undefined method `find' for "c":String
```

Comment: Could you define _"amount of duplicate characters"_? What's your expected result and why?

Comment: You've seen @Stefan's questions but you chose not to answer them. Why? Your question is unclear. Do you want the number of characters that appear at least twice? The total number of appearance of characters that appear at least twice? Do you want that for each such character or a single number taken over all such characters?

Comment: sorry i meant the count of any repeated characters.. so basically how many characters are duplicated in the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible solution:

```
string = "chineedne"
string.chars.uniq.count { |char| string.count(char) > 1 }
#=> 2
```

or without `uniq` method to count total amount of duplicated characters:

```
string = "chineedne"
string.chars.count { |char| string.count(char) > 1 }
#=> 5
```

In order to get away from N**2 complexity, you also can use `group_by` method for creating hash with `character` -> `array` that include all of this character from `string` and than just use this hash to get any data that you want:

```
duplicates = string.chars.group_by { |char| char }.select { |key, value| value.size > 1 } 
# or, for Ruby version >= 2.2.1 - string.chars.group_by(&:itself).select { |key, value| value.size > 1 }
```

than:

```
> duplicates.keys.size # .keys => ['n', 'e']
#=> 2
```

and

```
> duplicates.values.flatten.size # .values.flatten => ["n", "n", "e", "e", "e"]
#=> 5
```

Comment: N**2 complexity

Comment: To elaborate @llya's comment, `count` must traverse the string once for each unique character. That's very inefficient, considering that you can produce all those counts in a single pass, as llya has done with a counting hash. You can also us [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) for that purpose.

Comment: You can use `.group_by(&:itself)`)

Comment: @Ilya First, I wrote about it. Secondly, this method is available in versions of Ruby 2.2.1+(maybe in the some earlier, but in 1.9.3 not working). But thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply count your chars:

```
chars_frequency = str.each_char
                     .with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|c, m| m[c]+=1}
=> {"c"=>1, "h"=>1, "i"=>1, "n"=>2, "e"=>3, "d"=>1}
```

Then just count:

```
chars_frequency.count { |k, v| v > 1 }
=> 2
```

Or (if you want to count total amount):

```
chars_frequency.inject(0) {|r, (k, v)| v > 1 ? r + v : r }
=> 5
```

Comment: `each_with_object` → `with_object`

Comment: It's a shame there's no `count_by` in the stdlib

Answer (score 0):

I dont know too much about ruby but I think that something like this should work

```
yourstring = "chineedne"
count = 0
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("").each do |c|
  if (yourstring.scan(c).count > 1
    count = count+1
  end
end
```

count variable represents the ammount of duplicate characters
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12428037/6371926

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "chineedne"
```

# iterate over each chars creatign an array
  # downcase, incase we are dealing with case sensitive

```
arr = string.downcase.chars
```

# pulling out the uniq char and counting how many times 
  # they appear in the array more than once

```
arr.uniq.count {|n| arr.count(n) > 1}
```